# Make nginx rewrite relative

Tags: nginx

I have a web application (written by a different team) that comes with an nginx config snippet to provide rewrites:

```
rewrite ^list /ctrl/list.php last;
rewrite ^new /ctrl/new.php last;
```

This snippet can then be included in a server block in the nginx config:

```
server {
  server_name ...;

  include /path/to/snippet;
}
```

Unfortunately this only works as long as the application is hosted in the docroot. Even when the rewrites are in a `location` block...

```
server {
  server_name ...

  location /subdir/ {
    include /path/to/subdir/snippet
  }
}
```

... it does not work because both *regex* and *replacement* of `rewrite` are still relative to the docroot. Of course since the applications files don't know anything about `/subdir/` it cannot be included in the rewrites.

I somehow need to tell nginx to "treat all of the following rewrites relative to this subdirectory".

I could request the other team to include some kind of variable in the rewrites, but as far as I understand nginx doesn't have any kind of macro expansion in its config.

When the application is hosted on Apache, it works fine with the corresponding .htaccess file, because the rewrites in .htaccess are relative to the location of the .htaccess file. Still, I'd very much like to use nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it without recompiling nginx, I came up with a rather clumsy workaround. It's only needed when the include is actually used in a subdir location - when the application is installed in the root of the server block, the include can just be included.

The idea is to first rewrite every URI of that location block to itself without the subdir, then apply the included rewrite rules and finally rewrite them back to the subdir path:

```
server {
  server_name ...

  # This has to be a regex check because they run first:
  location ~ ^/subdir/ {
    rewrite ^/subdir/(.*) /$1;

    include /path/to/subdir/snippet
  }
  ...
```

Afterwards the initial rewrite has to be canceled by an additional rewrite in **every final location block**. This rewrite has the `break` flag set to make sure that the previous block won't be tried again (leading to an infinite loop that is run 10 times):

```
  location / {
    root   /var/www;

    rewrite ^(.*) /subdir$1 break;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;

    rewrite ^(.*) /subdir$1 break;
  }
```

---

I didn't try that yet, but it should be possible to get a much cleaner solution by recompiling nginx to add a custome module (all nginx modules are compiled in). This is [not too hard to do on Ubuntu](http://xdev.me/en/article/Recompile_Nginx_deb_package_with_a_new_module).

Even without recompiling it would be possible to add the subdirectory to the *replacement* part of the *rewrite* directive using a variable, so the hard part is to add it to the regex pattern. The `ngx_http_rewrite` module does not actually perform the regex matching but merely compiles it into an instruction (`ngx_http_script_regex_start_code`) for the `ngx_http_script` module. It [sets the `uri=1` parameter](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/src/http/modules/ngx_http_rewrite_module.c#L342) on the regex struct, which tells the `ngx_http_script` module to [use the current URI](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/src/http/ngx_http_script.c#L924) of the request.

So it should be possible to either add the current location prefix to the pattern or remove it from the URI before matching.