# Relative Nginx Rewrite Rules

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-301

I currently have an nginx instance which is solely used to retain traffic to an old url.

```
server {
listen xxx.xxx.IP.IP;
server_name  blog.store.com;
if ($http_host = "xxx.xxx.IP.IP"){return 301 $scheme://store.com;}
if ($http_host = blog.store.com){return 301 $scheme://store.com/blog;}
}
```

This works great but I want to add a rule that allows people to navigate to a sub directory of this and retain the rest of the path they hit.

Example: right now if someone hits a link that says 'blog.store.com/page' they are taken to 'store.com/blog'

I want them to be able to hit 'blog.store.com/page' and be taken to 'store.com/blog/page'

I've tried a few of the examples from

[URL Rewriting Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937603/url-rewriting-nginx)

[Make nginx rewrite relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795202/make-nginx-rewrite-relative)

But those and different variations of $1 do not work. Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please feel free to also paste the code that was not working for you (minimal code that shows the issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In the event you have not implemented the tutorials properly, people would be able to point out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard thank you very much here is my new code it worked.

```
server {
listen xxx.xx.xx.xxx:80;
server_name  blog.store.com;
if ($http_host = "xxx.xx.xx.xxx"){return 301 $scheme://store.com;}
if ($http_host = blog.store.com){return 301 $scheme://store.com/blog$request_uri;}
}
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
server {
  listen      xxx.xxx.IP.IP  default_server;
  return      301  $scheme://store.com;
}
server {
  listen      xxx.xxx.IP.IP;
  server_name blog.store.com;
  return      301  $scheme://store.com/blog$request_uri;
}
```